# Model Becomes a Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model name Enrollment. After checking it's class it shows that is a module. How did that happen?

Model:

```
enrollment.rb

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: What is your Application name?

Comment: Enrollment the same as the model. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can rename the model or rename the application by https://github.com/get/rename for example.